# R package with C code on Windows (win-build) fails to compile, ar: Command not found

Tags: r, windows, cran

I have a package that I'm trying to build on Windows using win-builder for CRAN. The compilation fails with this message:

```
ar -crs libmseed.a fileutils.o genutils.o gswap.o lmplatform.o lookup.o msrutils.o pack.o packdata.o traceutils.o tracelist.o parseutils.o unpack.o unpackdata.o selection.o logging.o
make[1]: ar: Command not found
```

This is my Makevars.win file:

```
PKG_CFLAGS=
PKG_CPPFLAGS=-Ilibmseed
PKG_LIBS=-Llibmseed -lmseed
$(SHLIB): libmseed/libmseed.a
libmseed/libmseed.a:
    @(cd libmseed && $(MAKE) static CC="$(CC)" CFLAGS="$(CFLAGS)" AR="$(AR)")
clean:
    @(cd libmseed && $(MAKE) clean)
```

I have also tried modifying the Makevars.win file using AR="ar mingw" and without AR specified. I get the same "ar: Command not found" message. Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

Comment: You should probably [re-]read https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html and examine the source of a few, small-ish C-backed packages (lots of them are on GitHub). You're making quite a number of assumptions about the environments you'll encounter.

Answer (score 0):

This is solved. I changed the Makefile from 
`ar -crs $(LIB_A) $(LIB_OBJS)`
to 
`$(AR) -crs $(LIB_A) $(LIB_OBJS)`
and now it compiles.

Comment: Please don't cross-post between the R maliing lists and here, and it would be fair to credit Bill Dunlap.